# What is new in MSC 2010?

Tags: journals, msc

Has anyone seen the new MSC 2010? I was browsing around and to my suprise there is another revision of MSC. Has anyone noticed any major changes in there? Do major journals already accept papers with MSC 2010 classification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got partial answer to my questions in the following sites:

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/conv.html?from=2000

and

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/conv.html?from=2010

Answer (score 3):

You can get a more complete answer here:

www.msc2010.org